# SQL/PostgreSQL: select all members except self

Tags: sql, postgresql

So my in my schema I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE group_members(
  group_id UUID NOT NULL,
  account_name TEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (group_id, account_name)
);
```

Let's say my account name is `peter` and I want to select all **other** members of some groups (matching a specific criteria, I'll explain later) in which I am a member in. I came up with two queries:

```
SELECT account_name,
       group_id
FROM   group_members
WHERE  group_id IN
       (
          SELECT group_id
          FROM   group_members
          WHERE  account_name = 'peter'
          INTERSECT
          SELECT unnest('{"550e8400-e29b-11d4-a716-446655440000"}' :: uuid []))
AND    group_members.account_name != 'peter';
```

and

```
WITH my_groups AS
(
   SELECT account_name,
          group_id
   FROM   group_members
   WHERE  account_name = 'peter'
   INTERSECT
   SELECT 'peter',
          unnest( '{"550e8400-e29b-11d4-a716-446655440000"}' :: uuid []))
SELECT group_members.account_name,
       group_members.group_id
FROM   group_members,
       my_groups
WHERE  my_groups.group_id = group_members.group_id
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM   my_groups;
```

The INTERSECT subquery takes an array of group ids and filters it for all the groups peter is a member in.

Which one should I use? Or is there a simpler way to do this? Because, honestly, both queries EXPLAIN looks scary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test performance on your data and choose the one best based on your requirements.  My inclination would be for the first approach, with a minor change:

```
SELECT account_name,
       group_id
FROM   group_members gm
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 1
               FROM group_members gm2
               WHERE gm2.account_name = 'peter' AND
                     gm2.group_id = gm.group_id
              ) AND
       gm.group_id IN (SELECT unnest('{"550e8400-e29b-11d4-a716-446655440000"}' :: uuid []) AND
       gm.account_name <> 'peter';
```

This method can take advantage of an index on `group_members(group_id, account_name)`.  With such an index, the query should be pretty fast -- scanning the index for the outer query and then getting matches using the index for the subquery.

It is possible that your versions would also have very good performance; sometimes, set operations such as `UNION` and `INTERSECT` affect the ability to use indexes.